# stop ttk.Entry() from reading keyboard

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

**Environment: macOS Catalina, Python 3.7.4, Tcl/Tk 8.6.9, VSC 1.39.1**

I have a situation where I am using a bar/qr code scanner to provide a string to a ttk.Entry() method, which then fires off a function.

The reader is seen by the OS as an HID keyboard, so the text from the QR code is received by the ttk.Entry() widget that I give focus to during code execution.  I have bound the widget to the  key because the scanner sends a cr/lf at the end of the text string, which works as needed.

However, I am running into an issue where if the qr code lingers over the scanner too long it will rescan the qr code and the widget receives the qr code text again, which then causes it to be processed again.

I have tried disabling the ttk.Entry() in the function, deleting the widget contents, and removing focus to no avail.  The behavior I'm seeing is occurring even though the widget is disabled and does not have focus, it is still getting input and executing the function again if the scanner rescans the qr code while the function is executing.

In this first example, I simply tried to disable the widget, but that doesn't work.  The widget still gets the later scans while in the function.

```
# test-ttk-entry1.py

import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import StringVar, ttk

root = tk.Tk()

def print_text(event):
    global kbEntry
    textValue = kbEntry.get()
    kbEntry.configure(state="disabled")
    time.sleep(2) # Add in a delay to allow for repeat scan
    print(textValue)
    time.sleep(2) # Add in a delay to allow for repeat scan
    kbEntry.configure(state="active")

kbText = StringVar()
kbEntry = ttk.Entry(root, width=10, textvariable=kbText)
kbEntry.bind("<Return>", print_text)
kbEntry.pack()
kbEntry.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```

The second attempt was to disable the entry widget and upon making it active again delete the text in the field.

```
# test-ttk-entry2.py

import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import END, StringVar, ttk

root = tk.Tk()

def print_text(event):
    global kbEntry
    textValue = kbEntry.get()
    kbEntry.delete(0, END)
    kbEntry.configure(state="disabled")
    time.sleep(2) # Add in a delay to allow for repeat scan
    print(textValue)
    time.sleep(2) # Add in a delay to allow for repeat scan
    kbEntry.configure(state="active")
    kbEntry.delete(0, END)

kbText = StringVar()
kbEntry = ttk.Entry(root, width=10, textvariable=kbText)
kbEntry.bind("<Return>", print_text)
kbEntry.pack()
kbEntry.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```

And finally, I was reading about taking focus from a widget and giving focus to the root window, so I added that in and it still prints multiple times to the console like there is a keyboard buffer being read by the ttk.Entry() widget.  The weird thing is it seems like widgets don't normally respond to any calls to methods when they are disabled, but it appears the ttk.Entry() widget's properties/attributes (excuse me if my OOP terms are not correct) can be manipulated while disabled.

```
# test-ttk-entry2.py

import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import END, StringVar, ttk

root = tk.Tk()

def print_text(event):
    global kbEntry
    textValue = kbEntry.get()
    kbEntry.delete(0, END)
    kbEntry.configure(state="disabled")
    root.focus_set()
    time.sleep(2) # Add in a delay to allow for repeat scan
    print(textValue)
    time.sleep(2) # Add in a delay to allow for repeat scan
    kbEntry.configure(state="active")
    kbEntry.delete(0, END)
    kbEntry.focus_set()

kbText = StringVar()
kbEntry = ttk.Entry(root, width=10, textvariable=kbText)
kbEntry.bind("<Return>", print_text)
kbEntry.pack()
kbEntry.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```

So how can I prevent the ttk.Entry() widget from accepting any input from the HID/keyboard device while my function is executing?

Comment: If I perform a subsequent call to kbEntry.get() within the function, the buffer is empty.  But as soon as the function is done, the Entry widget then picks up the subsequent scan of the QR code, like it is waiting in a buffer and the Entry widget sees it and the event is retriggered.

Comment: You can see this in action by entering '1234'<return> rapidly in the entry field.  Also this needs to be non-blocking.

Comment: I've been messing around with .pack_forget() to try and prevent the .Entry() widget from receiving multiple (duplicate) entries, but so far, that isn't working the greatest.  I guess I'll write my callback to hold a global string variable and check it for duplicate entries on successive calls and ignore the extra entries.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am unable to find a way to temporarily disable the .Entry() widget programmatically to keep it from reading successive inputs, I have come up with this solution:

```
# test-ttk-entry2.py

import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import END, StringVar, ttk

root = tk.Tk()
tempStr = "" # Global temporary string variable to trip repeated scans

def print_text(event):

    global tempStr

    textValue = kbEntry.get()
    if tempStr == textValue:
        kbEntry.delete(0, END)
        print ("Duplicate scan")
        return
    tempStr = textValue
    kbEntry.delete(0, END)
    print(textValue)
    time.sleep(3) # Simulate the time it takes for the function to complete

kbEntry = ttk.Entry(root, width=10)
kbEntry.bind("<Return>", print_text)
kbEntry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
kbEntry.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```